# nginx - serve only images

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup nginx so "static.domain.com" can only serve images. This is what I have come up with, but I know it can be done more efficiently. I want to serve 403.html if someone tries to access any .htm, .php, directory (anything else I'm missing?) files. Of course, with the exception of 403.htm and static.htm files.

Any ideas how I can secure this properly?

```
server {
     listen          xx.xx.xx.xx:80;

     server_name     static.domain.com;

     root            /www/domain.com/httpdocs;
     index           static.htm;

     access_log      off;
     error_log       /dev/null crit;

     error_page  403  /403.html;

     # Disable access to .htaccess or any other hidden file
     location ~ /\.ht  {
        deny all;
     }

     location ~* \.php {
        deny all;
     }

     # Serve static files directly from nginx
     location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
        add_header        Cache-Control public;
        add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
        expires           7d;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not move the images up and then deny all?

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
   add_header        Cache-Control public;
   add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
   expires           7d;
}
location  / {
    deny all; 
}
```

> there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead, match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then use location / to match anything else. -From http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Edit: Removed "=" from "location /" 
To quote the docs:

```
location  = / {
  # matches the query / *only.* 
}
location  / {
  # matches *any query*, since all queries begin with /, but regular
  # expressions and any longer conventional blocks will be
  # matched first.
}
```

My bad.

Comment: It's that simple? nothing else is needed?

Comment: Should be, of course I'd test it to be sure as I haven't run what I wrote there. The location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png...) matches all the types listed there seperated with pipes, if it doesn't then it will match "/" since "/" matches everything.

Comment: Ok, this won't work because in FireFox, any .php file that is accessed is allowing the user to download the file (shows download prompt).

Comment: No it works. I use this config myself (except that I redirect back to my normal domain instead of denying). A php ext will hit the second location and get denied. What is missing in your config is a "$" at the end of the allowed static extensions.

Comment: Sorry I thought I commented when I read this, I fixed the typo of the "=" in my original one. Check the edit. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of the "$" being needed .. now to fix my other configs ..

Comment: I think the order of entries doesn't matter. `location \ ` could be on top equivalently.