# nginx config for static and nodejs apps

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location

We are having multiple nodejs app running in different ports and using nginx as proxy. We are facing (504)  issue while accessing static files url due to some wrong regex in `nginx.conf`

Anybody came across similar url patterns. Any pointers will be helpful

`nginx version 1.8.0`

### 504 Gateway Issue

```
https://localhost:9443/js/app1/index.js
https://localhost:9443/css/app1/index.css

https://localhost:9443/js/app2/index.js
https://localhost:9443/css/app2/index.css
```

### App Url

```
https://localhost:9443/app1
https://localhost:9443/app2
https://localhost:9443/api/app1
https://localhost:9443/api/app2
```

### nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       9443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate;        # path to your cacert.pem
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certifiatekey;    # path to your privkey.pem
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /js {
          alias /path/to/static/files;
        }
        location /css {
          alias /path/to/static/files;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443; #nodejsapp1
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_buffering         on;
        }


        location ~ /app1/ {
          proxy_pass https://localhost:8143; #nodejsapp2
          error_page 502 = @fallback;
        }

        location ~ /app2 {
          proxy_pass https://localhost:8343; #nodejsapp3
          error_page 502 = @fallback;
        }

        location @fallback{
            rewrite ^ /maintenance;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    }



    include servers/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `https://localhost:9443/js/app1/index.js` matches the regular expression for app1, as it contains the text `/app1/`.

Regular expression locations take precedence over normal prefix locations, so the `location /js` block is not used in the above case.

Read [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to understand the evaluation order for the `location` directive.

You can move the precedence order of your `js` and `css` locations above all of the regular expression locations, by using the `^~` modifier:

```
location ^~ /js { ... }
location ^~ /css { ... }
```

These remain as prefix locations, but with a higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have tried  and it worked. Got help from this post
[nginx - serve only images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309357/nginx-serve-only-images)

```
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       9443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate;        # path to your cacert.pem
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certifiatekey;    # path to your privkey.pem
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js)$ {
            root /path/to/static/files;
            expires 30d;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443; #nodejsapp1
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_buffering         on;
        }


        location ~* /app1/ {
          proxy_pass https://localhost:8143; #nodejsapp2
          error_page 502 = @fallback;
        }

        location ~* /app2 {
          proxy_pass https://localhost:8343; #nodejsapp3
          error_page 502 = @fallback;
        }

        location @fallback{
            rewrite ^ /maintenance;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    }



    include servers/*;
}
```