# Nginx server images only

Tags: nginx, server

*******************************solved*****************************

```
    location ~ ^/images/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png))$
    {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            alias /site/$1;

    }
```

Not certain but I needed to add $1 to the end and changed the regex a little.

I have a route set up how do I only serve up png and jpg files.  Currently it serves up any extension.

```
 location /image {
     alias /site/;
 }
```

I've tired the following but received errors.

```
location /image \.(png|jpg)
{
  alias /site/;
}
```

I just want to show only png and jpg files in the directory.  Moving the files isn't an option. A lot of sub directories with images.

I've tried

```
location ~* ^/image/.+\.(png|jpg)$
```

I am getting no errors but the images aren't showing.  Yes the images are in the folder.

*********************** update *************************

This location block works if I put a redirect in the block.  But if I try to show the image via

```
location ~* /images2/.+\.(png|jpg)$
{
}
```

The error logs says the following

```
GET /images2/flowers/type/T.png/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

Comment: Maybe `location ~* ^/image.+\.(png|jpg)$`?

Comment: you forget `~` modifier 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Tried that and now no images show are showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx - serve only images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309357/nginx-serve-only-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*******************************solved*****************************

```
    location ~ ^/images/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png))$
    {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            alias /site/$1;

    }
```

Not certain but I needed to add $1 to the end and changed the regex a little.

Comment: Why did you need to include the `mime.types` file there?

Comment: I am not sure if I actually needed to add `mime.types`.  I think I added it because it was already in another location in the nginx conf file.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the response. I thought it was also necessary, but then I found that I have it already included, so I wondered, did I need to include it again or not :)